# Calling external function from within Phantomjs+node.js

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm going to be honest. I'm way in over my head here.

I need to scrape data from a dynamic site for my employer. Before the data is visible on the page, there are some clicks and waits necessary. Simple PHP scraping won't do. So I found out about this NodeJS + PhantomJS combo. Quite a pain to set up, but I did manage to load a site, run some code and get a result.

I wrote a piece of jQuery which uses timeout loops to wait for some data to be loaded. Eventually I get a js object that I want to write to a file (JSON).

The issue I'm facing. 
I build up the the js object inside the PhantomJS .evaluate scope, which runs in a headerless browser, so not directly in my Node.JS server scope. How do I send the variable I built up inside evaluate back to my server so I can write it to my file?

Some example code (I know it's ugly, but it's for illustrative purposes). I use node-phantom-simple as a bridge between Phantom and Node

```js
var phantom = require('node-phantom-simple'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  webPage = 'https://www.imagemedia.com/printing/business-card-printing/'

phantom.create(function(err, ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(err, page) {
    return page.open(webPage, function(err, status) {
      page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
      };
      console.log("opened site? ", status);
      page.evaluate(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.price-select-cnt').eq(0).find('select').val('1266').change()
          timeOutLoop()

          function timeOutLoop() {
            console.log('looping')
            setTimeout(function() {
              if ($('#ajax_price_tool div').length != 6) {
                timeOutLoop()
              } else {
                $('.price-select-cnt').eq(1).find('select').val('25')
                $('.price-select-cnt').eq(2).find('select').val('Premium Card Stock')
                $('.price-select-cnt').eq(3).find('select').val('Standard').change()
                timeOutLoop2()
              }
            }, 100)
          }

          function timeOutLoop2() {
            console.log('looping2')
            setTimeout(function() {
              if ($('.pricing-cost-cnt').text() == '$0' || $('.pricing-cost-cnt').text() == '') {
                timeOutLoop2()
              } else {
                var price = $('.pricing-cost-cnt').text()
                console.log(price)
              }
            }, 100)
          }
        }, 4000)
      });
    });
  });
});

function writeJSON(plsWrite) {
  var key = 'file'
  fs.writeFile('./results/' + key + '.json', plsWrite, 'utf8', function() {
    console.log('The JSON file is saved as');
    console.log('results/' + key + '.json');
  });
}
```

So do do I write the price this code takes from the website, get it out of the evaluate scope and write it to a file?

Comment: yes it a whole different scope in phantomjs but think it as a different application, how would you send data to your localhost server from a local webpage? you can send with Ajax or have phantom open another page and send data .

Comment: Normally I would use a post request to a PHP file which would write to the JSON file. But in my final code the JS object could contain up to 800000 characters. To long to be send by URL. 

Is there a way I can send that kind of data to another server? I figured it is just way too much..

Comment: 800000 chars is around ~0.7mb post requests can handle it but add it to the body not the url. Since you work with NodeJS create a bare minimum server and test it.

Comment: Do you even need node.js? You know that PhantomJS has its own script system, right? Scrape a page then [write](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/write.html) results to file straight from PhantomJS.